# Error al hacer el build desde webpack

Tags: npm, webpack, build

Como estan? estoy dando mis primeros pasos con `webpack` y me encontre con un problema que no logro resolver, al intentar hacer el *build* de un archivo `js`, me tira el siguiente error:

```
webpack test.js app.js
The CLI moved into a separate package: webpack-cli
Would you like to install webpack-cli? (That will run npm install -D webpack-cli) (yes/NO)yes
```

Al darle **yes** comienza la instalación, lo cual finaliza con el siguiente error:

> npm WARN deprecated babel-preset-es2015@6.24.1: �  Thanks for using
>   Babel: we recommend using babel-preset-env now: please read
>   babeljs.io/env to update! npm WARN deprecated nomnom@1.8.1: Package no
>   longer supported. Contact support@npmjs.com for more info.
>   D:_PROYECTOS\deploy `-- webpack-cli@2.0.14
>
> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.1.2
>   (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents): npm WARN notsup
>   SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3:
>   wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current:
>   {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"}) { Error: Cannot find module 'webpack-cli'
>       at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
>       at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
>       at runCommand.then.result (C:\Users\santa 64\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js:62:14)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }

Luego intento ejecutar nuevamente el comando de `webpack` para hacer el *build*

```
webpack test.js app.js
```

Pero nuevamente me tira el mismo error y no logro continuar.

Comment: Te falta npm i webpack-cli -g

Comment: gracias @JackNavaRow eso fue la solucion, ahora me esta tirando otro problema, me dice lo siguiente:

WARNING in configuration
The 'mode' option has not been set, webpack will fallback to 'production' for this value. Set 'mode' option to 'development' or 'production' to enable defaults for each environment.
You can also set it to 'none' to disable any default behavior. Learn more: https://webpack.js.org/concepts/mode/


imagino que es muy de principiante, pero todavia no se ni donde estan las configuraciones, mil gracias nuevamente

Answer (score 2):

@jackNavRow me dio la respuesta de como hacer para bajar la dependencia que faltaba.
Con esto ya estoy pudiendo ejecutar el comando de webpack que daba error

```
npm i webpack-cli -g
```

gracias!

Comment: en unos dias pasa nuevamente para aca y marca tu pregunta como aceptada

Answer (score 0):

Las lineas que muestras te dan la solución:

```
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
```

Esta línea te esta diciendo que el paquete `fsevents`, solo esta disponible para `darwin (OSX, mac)` y tu estas en un `Win32(windows)`.

En concreto que una de las dependencias no se puede instalar.

Comment: Si, pero no encentro la solucion, simplemente no puedo usar webpack o hay alguna manera de poder continuar?
Imagino que debe de existir alguna version de webpack para windows que corra.

intente ejcutar lo siguiente pero me sigue ocurriendo lo mismo
npm install --no-optional

Comment: Esto es un simple warning que se puede ignorar: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/161263/que-significa-estos-warn-en-la-terminal-de-node/